# How to share my environment variables with open source projects?

Tags: python, flask, github, backend

Hi so I'm new with running an open source project. Currently, I want to let other people contribute to my project, but I'm running into a problem right now. How would I share my environment variables which other users to make sure that their app runs locally. Is there a way to have contributors run my project locally without having all of their environment variables configured? I thought of having the person make their own environment variables, but since I have quite a bit of environment variables, I would like to avoid that.

Note: I'm running a Flask App for my backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally include a "run" script, which is in charge of:

- setting the right environment variables
- check the PATH for execution environment dependencies (making sure you have the right minimum version of some executable required to run your project)
- running the actual project.